# How to handle null in my own class to avoid NullPointerException

Tags: java, null

I am trying to build a class for my LinkedList as a practice, since I've worked it out in python before, I know I can easily set a method up in a recursive way to check if two linked list are equal:

```
class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;

    ListNode(int x) {
        val = x;
    }

    public boolean equals(ListNode other) {
        if (this == null && other == null) {
            return true;
        } else if (this == null || other == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return this.val == other.val && this.next.equals(other.next);
        }
    }
```

However, as this could work fine in python, it does not work in java (I got `NullPointerException`), which is not surprising, as I need to handle the situation of when the `node.next` is `null`, then  `null.equals(other)` can not be executed as `null` does not have a method `equals`:

So I came up with a static method that could work, but I don't like it very much.

```
public static boolean equals(ListNode self, ListNode other) {
    if (self == null && other == null) {
        return true;
    } else if (self == null || other == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return self.val == other.val && equals(self.next, other.next);
    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to handle such common situation?

OK, I gave a bit thought, and I can keep non-static by doing check the next value first:

```
public boolean equals(ListNode other) {
    if (this.next == null && other.next == null) {
        return this.val == other.val;
    } else if (this.next == null || other.next == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return this.val == other.val && this.next.equals(other.next);
    }
}
```

Is this a good way?

Comment: one point to be noted, i don't think here you need to check if this is equals to null. Because , if objected referenced by this is null, you won't be able to call equals on it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if there is a better way to handle such common
>   situation?

You can either put your code in a `try-catch` block like this,

```
public boolean equals(ListNode other) {
    try {
        if (this == null && other == null) {
            return true;
        } else if (this == null || other == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return this.val == other.val && this.next.equals(other.next);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        /* Handle Exception */
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or, you can simply handle the case where `node.next` can be `null`,

```
public boolean equals(ListNode other) {
    if (this == null && other == null) {
        return true;
    } else if (this == null || other == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (this.next != null) {
        return this.val == other.val && this.next.equals(other.next);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `this == null` will be `false`, always

Comment: @josejuan Thanks for pointing that out. The first statement will be a `No-Op` in this case. `else if (this.next != null)` should still do the trick!

Comment: I've always heard that it is not a good idea to use `try...catch` unless I absolutely need to. So I've always try not to build up something with this `try...catch..` method

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 If you know and, can handle the `NPEs` in your code then you don't need `try-catch` blocks. If you don't care much about the performance and, want an easy life then, you can use it by all means! There is nothing stopping you.

Comment: Well, in Java we were raised to never use try/catch for control flow like things, and to rather check for permission instead of asking for forgiveness. And yes, there is definitely a drastic performance hit from throwing an exception ... and catching it. Beyond that, try/catch like here, that surprises most readers. So, long story short: this is really bad practice, and if you would show up in one of my reviews with that, I would sent you home immediately ;-)

Comment: Kudos @GhostCat for basically stating the very very obvious thing. Catch alls like that  here are a recipe for disaster and should be avoided under all circumstances.

Comment: @GhostCat the thing is that most people are not really keen to follow this advise. There are several times where I found myself explaining why this is a very very bad concept even to - so called - seasoned developers, failing simple review for stuff like that. Same goes for catching any `Throwable`...

Comment: @Aris_Kortex Never say never. We have some situations where we catch LinkageError. Because that can happen when we put a bad fix on a system, and things are out of sync. It definitely helps us to catch those, to get a proper error log at the right place, and not 10 levels above on the outermost boundary ... because error.

Comment: @GhostCat true for extreme cases exceptions to the rule could be made but there are people that tend to abuse stuff like that..

Answer (score 1):

At first, your code looks pretty good and it's cool that you're thinking about writing nice code even for `equals` function.

**1)** Kind reminder is that `Object#equals` method takes `Object` as an argument, not the instance of the same class which declared this `#equals` (`ListNode` in our case).

**2)** Another point I can advice is not to put redundant `else` after `return` statements.

**3)** You can use standard `java.util.Objects.equals` method to make a reliable null-safe check.

**4)** At the end of the day, let's look how IDEA generates default `#equals` override for our `ListNode` class.
I've aligned the code to be readable and added clarifying comments:

```
package com.dpopov.rxjava.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Objects;

public class ListNode {

    private int val;

    private ListNode next;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        // if this is the same object as o, no further check required
        if (this == o)
            return true;

        // case handles other object == null and different class of other Object
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        // now we now that o can be cast to ListNode
        final ListNode listNode = (ListNode) o;

        return (val == listNode.val) // primitive type cast comparison require no null-checks
            && Objects.equals(next, listNode.next); // utility method takes care of nulls
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(val, next);
    }
}
```

**5)** In my opinion, this `#equals` implementation looks close to perfect.
Only option I'd maybe do is to split final logical expression and second `if` into separate `if` statements to make everything a one-level and simple logical expressions and to always "fail-first", i.e. return `false` in all possible cases for our `equals` method:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    // if this is the same object as o, no further check required
    if (this == o)
        return true;

    // other object is null (remember that this is not null)
    if (o == null)
        return false;

    // Object has different class
    if (getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;

    // now we now that o can be cast to ListNode
    final ListNode listNode = (ListNode) o;

    // negative case 1
    if (val != listNode.val) {
        return false;
    }

    // negative case 2
    if ( !Objects.equals(next, listNode.next) ) { // utility method takes care of nulls
        return false;
    }

    // all negative cases handled, the objects are now definitely equal
    return true;
}
```

But this is already mostly a matter of taste. One can reasonably argue that a simple logical expression is more clear.